# How can I guarantee order of execution/presentation of tasks in GPars threadpool?

Tags: multithreading, groovy, gpars

I'm running a set of tasks using a Gpars thread pool. The task execution times are very variable, from a few seconds to 20 minutes. (These are cucumber feature files FWIW.)

As luck would have it, the last task in the `features` list takes the longest to run, so the whole process sits there executing runtest('australian_government_rebate.feature') for 25 minutes when all the other threads have completed.

This means that multi-threading is not living up to its promise. The single-threaded tests take 65 minutes to run, the multi-threaded ones 48 mins. I was hoping for 30 mins or better.

My solution is to sort the feature files by previous execution time:

```
features = ...
features.sort { a, b -> b.executionTime() <=> a.executionTime() }
GParsPool.withPool(noOfCores) {
    features.eachParallel { feature ->
        runtest(feature)
    }
}
```

My question is this: can I guarantee that the features will be presented to the GParsPool in the order they occur in `features`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For cases like this one I'd recommend using dataflow tasks started from within a sequential for loop on a sorted collection of "features", instead of parallel collections:

```
PGroup group = ...
for(f in features) group.task {runtest(it)}
```

This would guarantee the startup order that you intend.

Comment: Vaclav many thanks for your help. I used `DefaultPGroup(4)` for `group`, then `group.shutdown()` at the end of the tests to make sure they completed. The tests still finished prematurely. Any ideas why? I thought shutdown() was supposed to be polite :-)

Comment: You have to wait for the tasks to finish, perhaps something like: features.collect {group.task{runtest(it)}}*.join() - the "task" method returns a Promise for each started task and before you shutdown() the pool, you should ensure calling join() on all Promises.

Answer (score 0):

Guarantee? No. But extremely likely. I think practically seen your approach is a good one, if you have execution times differing that much.